# Custom grid with strange proportions

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-layout-weight

I've created a custom grid that, in a specific case, must have 2x2 images.
My XML code is this:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_immagine_sx1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/cibo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_immagine_dx1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/cibo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_immagine_sx2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/cibo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/iv_immagine_dx2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/cibo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

I would to obtain a symmetric grid, where each row has same width/height and each column has same width/height.

The problem is that running code on a physical device I have this situation as shown below.

[image: image on physical device]

The rows are not with same height...why??
How can I fix the problem?

Thank you for your help.

---

EDIT:

As suggested by @Rashiq, I added weight_sum to the horizontal LinearLayouts but is not fixed yet.

As suggested by @S Praveen Kumar, I tried to use TabLayout with code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/cibo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/cibo" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

But no news, the problem persists.

But attention, i can see that **the problem is present when the image sources have different sizes**...
How can I fix it?

Comment: Just a suggestion, why don't you use a TableLayout instead?

Comment: Specify weight_sum to horizontal linear layout and check if it solves your issue... otherwise try tablelayout

Comment: @SPraveenKumar thanks for help, I've edited my post. The problem persists.

Comment: @Rashiq, thanks, I edited my post as answer of your suggestion too.

Comment: @ClaudioP I doubted this. You should try experimenting with scaleType for the imageView. Try something like fitCenter or fitXY.

Comment: The image in the second row is fully loading but is not equally in height as frst row.. is that your issue? Or something else.. im a bit not clear with the issue right now

Comment: @Rashiq you are right, it's this the problem

Comment: @SPraveenKumar fitCenter and fitXY don't fix the problem

Comment: Ok!! Since you have used weightsum to both child linear layouts, it would wrap the height of image you added. Inorder to solve the issue, you can either set an default height to linear layouts, or to the imageview. Or simply try using grid view. And also try using android:adjustviewbounds true to imageviews

Comment: @Rashiq, setting heigth to the LinearLayouts it works, but doing this it creates a constraint between container layout (layout that contains this grid) and the grid..if one day i will modify the height of the container layout i have to modify the height of the grid (the height of two LinearLayouts) too in order to maintain the proportions...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem:

First of all find **parent layout's width**:

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int width = parentLayout.getWidth();
            parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            //initiate your grid here

        }
    });
```

And set your **grid child layout's width and height** as above **obtained width**, results a square image.